# How to handle errors in Firestore transactions inside https cloud function?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, google-cloud-functions, try-catch

I want to throw an https error to the client if some pre-condition fails (in the read part of the transaction). Also, I want to throw an "unavailable" error if the transaction fails because of an unexpected error.

```
await firestore
  .runTransaction(async (transaction) =>
    transaction.get(userRef).then((doc) => {
        const { totalPoints } = doc.data();

        if (totalPoints > 1000) {
          ...
        } else {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            "failed-precondition",
            "You have less than 1000 points."
          );
        }
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "unavailable",
      "Please, try again later."
    );
  });
```

The problem is that, if I throw the https error inside the then, the catch will get it and throw an other https error.

How can I avoid entering the catch when throwing the  "failed-precondition" error?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem with Promise.reject()

I know that this is not the best way, but works. Looking for a better approach.

```
await firestore
  .runTransaction(async (transaction) =>
    transaction.get(userRef).then((doc) => {
        const { totalPoints } = doc.data();

        if (totalPoints > 1000) {
          ...
        } else {
          return Promise.reject({
            type: "failed-precondition",
            message: "You have less than 1000 points."
          });
        }
    })
  )
  .catch((err) => {
     if (err.type === "failed-precondition") {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err.type, err.message);
     }
     else {
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
          "unavailable",
          "Please, try again later."
       );
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

For all of my Cloud Functions, I have a top-level try-catch that catches unknown errors and lets HttpsError errors continue down the chain as they are.

```
if (e instanceof https.HttpsError) throw e;
console.error("Encountered with an undefined error. Error: ", e);
throw new https.HttpsError(
  "unknown",
  "There was an unknown error."
);
```

You can do a similar thing (replacing https.HttpsError with functions.https.HttpsError of course).

This allows me to pass on the errors I have pre-defined inside the code as they are, and also provide my users an error message while logging the error for Cloud Logging.